# Using Drupal's navbar content on a non-Drupal site?

Tags: angularjs, api, drupal, playframework, navigation

Can you fetch a Drupal navbar to be used on a non-Drupal site? The goal is to have the same nav on 2 sites, of which the other is a Drupal site and the other is not (it's Play + AngularJS). We want the navbar to be updated by non-technical Drupal users, in the Drupal interface. For maintainability we'd like the other site's navbar content to be updated based on Drupal's.

One way I've been thinking is by using some sort of API for the nav links. E.g. if the Drupal navbar had the items "Home" (`link_1.com/`), "About" (`link_1.com/about`) and Contact (`link_1.com/contact`), I could fetch those in JSON (or some other format) from a Drupal API (?) and then display them on my non-Drupal site. Could this be implemented in Drupal and how? Is there some other, better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/services_menu ... this will help you create an endpoint at which you can get the entire menu structure.